# SharePoint Group Permissions in Lists

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, groups

I would like to create a SharePoint list and authorize different existing SharePoint groups on it. However, the group members should only be able to see or edit their own entries, or the entries of their group in the list. Furthermore, a group should be able to see and edit all entries in the list. How to resolve this in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method, you can use CSOM to display the specific items as you want. Use **[SPWeb.CurrentUser.Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.currentuser.aspx)** to get the collection of groups of which the user is a member. And use [**CAML query**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544234.aspx) (**Membership** Element) to filter on items created by current user or created by the members of the current user’s groups.

**Demo:**

Note: Change “cl_latest” to your list name.

```
<div id="displayDiv"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    //This example gets the items in the cl_Latest list that created by user or created by user group's memberships.   
    //This variable will hold the list items collection  
    var returnedItems = null;
    var groups = null;  
    var groupId="";
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getGroups);
    function getGroups(){
        //Get the current context   
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
        var oWeb = context.get_web();
        //Get current user
        var currentUser = oWeb.get_currentUser();
        //Gets the collection of groups of which the user is a member
        groups = currentUser.get_groups();
        context.load(groups);
        context.executeQueryAsync(loopGroups, onFailedCallback);
    }

    function loopGroups(){
        if (groups !== null){
            var groupEnumerator = groups.getEnumerator();
            var queryString1 = "<View><Query><Where>";
            var queryString2 = "";
            while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var group = groupEnumerator.get_current();
                var gId = group.get_id();
                queryString2 += "<Membership Type='SPGroup' ID='"+gId+"'><FieldRef Name='Author'/></Membership></Or>"
                queryString1 += "<Or>"
                console.log("id: "+gId);
            } 
            console.log(queryString1);
            var queryString3 = queryString1 + "<Eq><FieldRef Name= 'Author'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer'/></Value></Eq>"+queryString2;
            queryString3 += "</Where></Query></View>";
            console.log(queryString3);
            queryListItems(queryString3);

        }
    }


    function queryListItems(queryString) { 
        //console.log("run group id:"+groupId);
        var context2 = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
        //Get the Announcements list. Alter this code to match the name of your list  
        var list = context2.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('cl_latest');       
        //Create a new CAML query  
        var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();  
        //Create the CAML that will return   
        caml.set_viewXml(queryString);  
        //Specify the query and load the list oject  
        returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);  
        context2.load(returnedItems);  
        //Run the query asynchronously, passing the functions to call when a response arrives  
        context2.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);  
    }  

    //This function fires when the query completes successfully  
    function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) { 
        console.log("Display items for group:"+groupId);    
        //Get an enumerator for the items in the list  
        var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();  
        //Formulate HTML from the list items  
        var markup = '';  
        //Loop through all the returned items  
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {  
            var listItem = enumerator.get_current();  
            markup += 'Item Title: ' + listItem.get_item('Title') + '<br>';  
            markup += 'Item ID: ' + listItem.get_id() + '<br>';  
            markup += 'Create By: ' + listItem.get_item('Author').get_lookupValue() + '<br><br>'; 
        }  
        //Display the formulated HTML in the displayDiv element  
        displayDiv.innerHTML += markup;  
    }  
    //This function fires when the query fails  
    function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {  
        console.log("Display items for group:"+groupId);
        //Formulate HTML to display details of the error  
        var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>';  
        markup += 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>';  
        //Display the details  
        displayDiv.innerHTML += markup;  
    }  
</script>
```

Add the following code to a page. It will only display the items from the specific list which created by the current user or created by the members of the current user’s groups.

Answer (score 4):

Create multiple views and set [target audience](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293) for showing different view for different user group. Use caml query ([Membership Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544234.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and SPGroup type) to get all users from the specific group for filtering the items in the list view based on the current user or the user group where the current user belongs to.

1. Create a view and set filter Created by = [Me].
   [image]
2. Edit the list in SharePoint Designer and edit the view in advanced mode.
3. Find the following caml query:

> ```
> <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Author"/><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer"/></Value></Eq></Where>
> ```

Change it to:

```
 <Where><Or><Membership Type="SPGroup" ID="8"><FieldRef Name="Author"/></Membership><Eq><FieldRef Name= "Author"/><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer"/></Value></Eq></Or></Where>
```

[image]
Note: the number 8 in ID="8" is the id of the group. You can find it from the page where you see membership of the group: /_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=id
[image]

4. Save the changes and open the list in browser.

   This view will only display the items created by the members in the group of current user, works as expected.
   [image]
5. Open this view and edit the page > edit the list view web part. Under Advanced section and enter the user group in the target audience.

   [image]
6. Repeat the above steps for each group.
7. For the admin group (a group should be able to see and edit all entries in the list), just use the All Items view.

Check the Hemendar Agrawal’s answer in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/318d300e-5cca-4aa7-afdb-ba3ab5a467cf/how-to-set-permissions-so-that-users-can-only-seeedit-thier-own-items-on-a-list?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i'm sure this would work, but unfortunately i have to use the foundation version of SP 2013, so the "target audiences" option is not available...

Answer (score 3):

I will try below approach

1. Create folder for each group. (If new folder option is disabled in list. Please check [this link](http://wiki.plexhosted.com/kb/Microsoft_SharePoint_2013:Create_a_new_folder_in_a_list_or_a_library#Enabling_the_.E2.80.9CNew_Folder.E2.80.9D_option) to enable.)
2. Give edit/contribute permission to respective group on respective folder. Please refer [this link](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-set-unique-permissions-for-folders-and-documents/) to manage permission on folder.
3. Give access to Admin group on all folders
4. This way users from one group will not able to see items of other groups as they will not have access on other groups folders.